# How to show datas in Laravel app.blade.php based on authenticated user id

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I have this app.blade.php in `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`:

```
<div>
    @include('assets.select', ['name'=>'current_company', datas=>$companys, 'required' => true, 'selected' => 1])
</div>
```

Here I need to show the user's company list in a html select field. I created a `middleware` called SetViewVariables, and registered into the `Kernel.php` in the `$middleware` array, like this:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\SetViewVariables::class,
```

And here is the SetViewVariables.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use DB;

class SetViewVariables
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
            $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            $userdata = Auth::user();
            $company = DB::table('company_users')
                            ->join('company','company_users.company_id','=','company.id')
                            ->select('company.id AS value','company.name AS name')
                          ->where('company_users.user_id','=',$userdata->id)
                            ->orderBy('company.name')
                            ->get();
            view()->share('companys', $company);

            return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The `$userdata` is always empty, so the `$userdata->id` is undefined too.

How can I get the logged user's id at this point? Or is there a better way to push $company datas to app.blade.php ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a [ViewComposer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) to display data in a specific blade view instead of (ab)using Middleware for that.

Another solution would be passing the variables in the controller, but the ViewComposer is arguably the best solution for this scenario.

This would be the compose function part of your ViewComposer.

```
....
public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('userdata', Auth::users()->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: not the share is the problem. The problem is the `Auth::user()` returns empty in the middleware.

Comment: Yeah, but it won't do so in the ViewComposer (when your Authentication is set up correctly). Try out my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In the middleware Auth::user() can return empty only if:

1) User not logged in

2) Your middleware try to access user datas in wrong time, for example when the session isn't exists.

Because of your middleware is in `$middleware` array, the `$middlewareGroups` did not run yet and in the time of running, the session isn't exists.

The solution:

1) Move your middleware from $middleware into the end of $middlewareGroups array

or

2) Move your session handler middlewares from $middlewareGroups into the $middleware (before your middleware).